# Javascript: how to change image-size for several blocks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

I need to change background image size for several **dinamic** blocks:

```
<div class="preview" style="background:url(http://site/image1.jpg)"></div>
<div class="preview" style="background:url(http://site/image2.jpg)"></div>
<div class="preview" style="background:url(http://site/image3.jpg)"></div>
```

This is a way how I try to set background size:

```
$('div.preview').each(function(){
    var x = y = 98;

    ths = $(this);
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = $(this).css('background-image').slice(4, -1);

    img.onload = function(e){
         if (this.width > this.height)
         {
             var scale = 100 * 98 / this.width;

             if (scale < 100)
             {
                 ths.css('background-size', 'auto ' + (100 - scale + 2) + '%');
             }
         }
         else
         {
             var scale = 100 * 98 / this.height;

             if (scale < 100)
             {
                 ths.css('background-size', (100 - scale + 4) + '% auto');
             }
         }
    }
});
```

But in this case image-size changes only for image3.jpg. How to change others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ths` is *not* a local variable.

So, for *every element* processed by `.each`, the same *global property* (`window.this`) is re-assigned. The last time it is assigned, it refers to "image3" - and thus all the asynchronous `onload` events, which occur later, will refer to "image3".

The quickest fix is to add `var` and change the code to:

```
var ths = $(this);
```

This makes `ths` a local variable, which will be *distinct* for each element processed by `.each`  (as each element is processed in a new function scope), that is *bound in the closure* formed by the `onload` callbacks.

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yHBNZ/1/) (thanks, Ani!)